# Spotify API getting artist track data returning error unauthorized

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently trying to fetch KD Rusha to get current tracks. Display it on his website and show play button when every someone hover over the song image to play it. What am I doing wrong here?

My Steps:

1. Want to fetch for KD Rusha top albums on spotify.
2. Limit them to only 9 tracks.
3. Add play button on top of each track to play 30 sec of the song.

   Artist ID `https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{id}` Give Me  `401 (Unauthorized)`

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   require('dotenv').config();

   export default class SpotifyComponent extends React.Component {

   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          artist: null,
       };
   }

   componentWillMount() {
       var request = new Request('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/5JLWikpo5DFPqvIRi43v5y', {
         method: 'GET',
         headers: new Headers({
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain',

         'Authorization': 'Bearer <big blob of token here>'
         })
   });

     fetch(request)// fetch the Spotify date from KD Rusha Account
       .then((response) => {
         var result = response.json()
           this.setState({// State artist albums
             albums: result,
             selectedTrack: [0]
           });
                   console.log(response.json());
       if (response.status >= 400) {
         throw new Error("Bad response from server");
       }
       return response.json();
     });
   }

     render(){
       return(
         <section className="spotify-cantainer">
                 <img src="{albums}" alt="kdrusha" />
         </section>
       );
     }

   }
   ```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct token? Did you request it a long time ago? It might have expired

Comment: posting your real api token is not recommended :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be entirely wrong, but since no one has replied to you yet and I have found a solution for a very similar problem thanks to your code, I will try to help. Here is my code, a function hooked to an input that will search for an artist using my Spotify login:

```
search () {
const BASE_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?';
const FETCH_URL = `${BASE_URL}q=${this.state.query}&type=artist&limit=1`;

fetch(FETCH_URL, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: new Headers({
    Accept: "application/json",
    Authorization: "Bearer <long token here>"
  })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log('json', json));
}
```

One difference is that the keys in my Headers dict are not in quotes. The function returns a json object with all the information regarding the artist from {this.state.quesry}.

Best of luck and I hope this helps!